# Distinct Number in a Multiline Textbox

Tags: vb.net

How do I make this code for a multiline Textbox?

```
AllNumbers1.AddRange(CType(TabControl2.TabPages(2).Controls("txtIntDraw" & x), TextBox).Text.Split(CChar(",")))
```

This code wants to be transformed, `txtIntDraw.Lines (i).`

That's all the Code:

```
  Try
            'Throw everything into a list of String initially.
            Dim AllNumbers1 As New List(Of String)
            'Loop through each TextBox, splitting them by commas
            For x = 1 To Val(txtXCount.Text)
                AllNumbers1.AddRange(CType(TabControl2.TabPages(2).Controls("txtIntDraw" & x), TextBox).Text.Split(CChar(",")))
            Next
            'Remove non-integer entries.
            AllNumbers1.RemoveAll(Function(x) Integer.TryParse(x, New Integer) = False)
            'Join the distinct list to an array, then back to comma separated format into wherever you want it output.
            OutputText1.Text = String.Join(",", AllNumbers1.Distinct().ToArray())
            Dim part() As String = OutputText1.Text.Split(",")
            Dim partCount As Integer = part.Length
            TextBox6.Text = partCount
            Array1()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```

Comment: If you are saying that you want to split by lines rather than on ",", you could use `.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to split on both NewLines and `,` at the same time, or just one or the other

Comment: Don't work - .Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it this simple? Instead of joining the distinct numbers with `","`, use `Environment.NewLine`.

```
OutputText1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, AllNumbers1.Distinct())
```

But your code can be simplified into a method

```
Private Sub doStuff(delimitersIn As String(), delimiterOut As String)
    Dim allNumbers As New List(Of Integer)()
    For x = 1 To CInt(txtXCount.Text)
        allNumbers.AddRange(TabControl2.TabPages(2).Controls("txtIntDraw" & x).Text.Split(delimitersIn, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(Function(s) Integer.TryParse(s, New Integer)).Select(Function(s) CInt(s)))
    Next
    Dim distinctNumbers = allNumbers.Distinct()
    OutputText1.Text = String.Join(delimiterOut, distinctNumbers)
    TextBox6.Text = distinctNumbers.Count().ToString()
End Sub
```

Call it with both delimiters

```
doStuff({Environment.NewLine, ","}, ",")
```

Or just the newline

```
doStuff({Environment.NewLine}, ",")
```